# Disable option when clicked in select

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick

How do I make disable an option when a `select` is clicked? Here is my code, which does not work. There are no errors in the console.

Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var numSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("numSelector");
            for (var i = 0; i < numSelect.length; i++) {
                numSelect[i].innerHTML="<span class='firstSelector'><option>Select Number</option></span><option>1/2</option>";
                numSelect[i].onclick = disableSelect;

            }
        }
        function disableSelect() {
            for (var a = 0; a < document.getElementsByClassName("firstSelector").length; a++) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("firstSelector")[i].innerHTML="<optgroup>Select Number</optgroup>";
            }

        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select class="numSelector"></select>
        <select class="numSelector"></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have span as a child of select

Comment: what are you really trying to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want but here is the ways to disabled dropdown value.

```
<select id="select1" onclick="disableSelectedItem(this);">
    <option>Select Number</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" onclick="disableFirstItemOnly(this);">
    <option>Select Number</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableSelectedItem(ddl) {
        var value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        var count = ddl.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (ddl.options[i].value == value) 
                ddl.options[i].disabled = true;
            else 
                ddl.options[i].disabled = false;
       }
     }

     function disableFirstItemOnly(ddl) {
         ddl.options[0].disabled = true;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorta what I wanted. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use pure *HTML*

```html
<select required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Number</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>etc..</option>
</select>
```

You could also add the *hidden* attribute if you don't want it to show up in the dropdown too (at the moment it is visible but disabled)

The *required* attribute on the `<select>` means that not choosing a number will prevent submission (though you should still validate serverside)

Comment: Awesome, but I am not using a `form` interface. I am using pure _JS._ :) but I will still take a look.